# How to annotate selectors in Objective-C disassembly?

Tags: objective-c, selector, reverse-engineering, disassembly, otool

From an unencrypted binary compiled from Objective-C, I can view the assembly of functions and methods, annotated with the names of called C functions, with the command `otool -tV`. However, Objective-C method calls always show as calls to `objc_msgSend()`. It does not show the selector (name of the method) called.

Is there a way to get it to annotate the called selector when there is a method call?

Comment: I don't know a way to do this with otool, but [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com) provide this kind of information.

Comment: @Markus: Yeah, any tool is acceptable. Though Hopper is a paid app. But I guess the demo still gives useful information.